# Count the number of adjacent equal elements in 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find a number of adjacent elements in a 2D array. When I say adjacent, I mean both horizontally and vertically.

For example:

```
[[1, 2, 1, 3],
 [2, 1, 3, 1],
 [3, 2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 2, 1]]
```

The result of this array will be 5, since the three 1s all the way right + the two 3s in the middle are adjacent to each other. What would be the least time-consuming way to achieve this, assuming the given 2d array can be larger than the example I gave here?

Thank you.

Comment: What about wrapping? e.g. if one of the arrays has the same value in its first and last elements?

Comment: Hey! Yes, I meant equal elements, and adjacent means both horizontally and vertically. I'll edit the question! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the popular problem of counting the number of the island.
Normally, the counting island problem is represented as a matrix of 0s and 1s.
e.g.

```
[
[0 1 0],
[1 1 0],
[0 1 0],
]
```

So, starting from there you could do a BFS to counts the similar (equal) adjacent number instead of 1s.

bellow is just a simplification of the problem

```
A = [[]]
visited = [[]] // matrix of booleans, contains the already visited i,j
for i in range(1, len(mat)):
    for j in range(1, len(mat[i])):
       BFS(A[i][j], A, i, j, visited)
```

then,

```
func BFS(target, matrix, i, j, visited):
   // do the normal island count logic, but using "target" instead of 1s
```

Ref.

https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

https://www.techiedelight.com/count-the-number-of-islands/